# Reading album art using php-reader (zend)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been trying to use the Zend Id3v2 class ([php-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/)) to get the album artwork (apic) from an MP3, but it doesn't seem to want to work properly. Is there a different php-reader library available that has been proven to work?

Also, for some reason all of the require_once calls in the function are set to 'Zend/...' and not to an absolute path like require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Zend...', which breaks them because they are trying to get to a subfolder called 'Zend' in the current directory which is a sub directory of Zend. I also can't use Finder & Replace to set it to an absolute path without going through each file manually, as the files in this class are locked. SMH FACEPALM

Comment: the reason these files are named and included as they are is because they are designed to work in a Zend Framework MVC application. so the default location for these files (in ZF app) is typically `application/library/Zend`. I've been having a terrible time making this library work as well. Include some of the code you are trying and maybe we can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 1 is written with the assumption that the folder where your `Zend` is stored is on the include_path.

e.g.

```
define('LIBRARY_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../library');

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(LIBRARY_PATH),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

This assumes that you're running this code in a sibling folder to `library` and that your Zend Framework files are in `library/Zend`